# i cant start a new line in the terminal of python

Tags: python

I don't know how to start a new line to enter more code in the python terminal. I have tried a lot of things, but I still don't know. I am a beginner, so i don't know allot about python. I have tried ctr+j, ;, \ and ;. Can somebody please help me? ps. i am using IDLE. pps. i fixed it by using notepad++. case closed.

Comment: Unless you're trying very simple things out, you should probably be using an editor or IDE to write your script into a .py file, then run it, instead of using the terminal/REPL alone.

Comment: Does the "enter" key not do what you want?

Answer (score 4):

The Python REPL will provide `...` to indicate a line continuation if it's relevant, like if you're writing a function or something like that.

```
>>> def foo():
...     print("Hello, World!")
... 
>>> foo()
Hello, World!
```

otherwise, you should use a text editor/IDE to edit your code. I'm preferential to VS Code, but there are lots of good ones.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: you're going to need to be more specific... I offered 2 options in my answer